# What are some examples of $K_{3,3}$ configuration?

Tags: graph-theory

by definition, a subgraph is a $K_{3,3}$ configuration if it can be obtained from a $K_{3,3}$ by adding vertices in the middle of some edges. 
But I still don't understand the definition. Can anyone show me an example of $K_{3,3}$ configuration and how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of pictures of $K_{3,3}$:

[image]

[image]

and adding some vertices for a  $K_{3,3}$ configuration:

[image]

where you can recover the $K_{3,3}$ , eliminating degree-2 vertices and joining the adjacent vertices (and also eliminating any duplicate edges, which don't figure in this example).